# Redirect output to a bash array

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

I have a file containing the string

```
ipAddress=10.78.90.137;10.78.90.149
```

I'd like to place these two IP addresses in a bash array. To achieve that I tried the following:

```
n=$(grep -i ipaddress /opt/ipfile |  cut -d'=' -f2 | tr ';' ' ')
```

This results in extracting the values alright but for some reason the size of the array is returned as 1 and I notice that both the values are identified as the first element in the array. That is

```
echo ${n[0]}
```

returns

```
10.78.90.137 10.78.90.149
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

do you really need an array

bash

```
$ ipAddress="10.78.90.137;10.78.90.149"
$ IFS=";"
$ set -- $ipAddress
$ echo $1
10.78.90.137
$ echo $2
10.78.90.149
$ unset IFS
$ echo $@ #this is "array"
```

if you want to put into array

```
$ a=( $@ )
$ echo ${a[0]}
10.78.90.137
$ echo ${a[1]}
10.78.90.149
```

@OP, regarding your method: set your IFS  to a space

```
$ IFS=" "
$ n=( $(grep -i ipaddress file |  cut -d'=' -f2 | tr ';' ' ' | sed 's/"//g' ) )
$ echo ${n[1]}
10.78.90.149
$ echo ${n[0]}
10.78.90.137
$ unset IFS
```

Also, there is no need to use so many tools. you can just use awk, or simply the bash shell

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr
while IFS="=" read -r caption addresses
do
 case "$caption" in 
    ipAddress*)
        addresses=${addresses//[\"]/}
        arr=( ${arr[@]} ${addresses//;/ } )
 esac
done < "file"
echo ${arr[@]}
```

output

```
$ more file
foo
bar
ipAddress="10.78.91.138;10.78.90.150;10.77.1.101"
foo1
ipAddress="10.78.90.137;10.78.90.149"
bar1

$./shell.sh
10.78.91.138 10.78.90.150 10.77.1.101 10.78.90.137 10.78.90.149
```

gawk

```
$ n=( $(gawk -F"=" '/ipAddress/{gsub(/\"/,"",$2);gsub(/;/," ",$2) ;printf $2" "}' file) )
$ echo ${n[@]}
10.78.91.138 10.78.90.150 10.77.1.101 10.78.90.137 10.78.90.149
```

Comment: The values are used later in the script. If they are stored in an array it would make it easier to iterate and perform other operations on them, hence the need to store them in an array. The method you describe should help me. Thanks!

Could you please share your thoughts on why the method I'm using is failing?

Answer (score 9):

This one works:

```
n=(`grep -i ipaddress filename | cut -d"=" -f2 | tr ';' ' '`)
```

EDIT: (improved, nestable version as per Dennis)

```
n=($(grep -i ipaddress filename | cut -d"=" -f2 | tr ';' ' '))
```

Comment: This does not work. BTW, isn't the expression same as the one I'm using? Is there any difference between using $() and ` (backticks)?

Comment: It works for me. This is what it would look like with `$()`: `n=($(grep -i ipaddress filename | cut -d"=" -f2 | tr ';' ' '))` - the outer parentheses make it into an array. It's better to use `$()` because they can be nested and it's easier to get quoting and escaping right and they're more readable: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Thanks Dennis, the non-backtick version is definitely better.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on a theme:

```
$ line=$(grep -i ipaddress /opt/ipfile)
$ saveIFS="$IFS"    # always save it and put it back to be safe
$ IFS="=;"
$ n=($line)
$ IFS="$saveIFS"
$ echo ${n[0]}
ipAddress
$ echo ${n[1]}
10.78.90.137
$ echo ${n[2]}
10.78.90.149
```

If the file has no other contents, you may not need the `grep` and you could read in the whole file.

```
$ saveIFS="$IFS"
$ IFS="=;"
$ n=$(</opt/ipfile)
$ IFS="$saveIFS"
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
n=($(perl -ne 's/ipAddress=(.*);/$1 / && print' filename))
```

which tests for and removes the unwanted characters in one operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `IFS` in `bash`.

- First read the first line from file.
- Seoncd convert that to an array with `=` as delimeter.
- Third convert the value to an array with `;` as delimeter.

Thats it !!!

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='\n' read -r lstr < "a.txt"
IFS='=' read -r -a lstr_arr <<< $lstr
IFS=';' read -r -a ip_arr <<< ${lstr_arr[1]}
echo ${ip_arr[0]}
echo ${ip_arr[1]}
```