# BASH: Send output of complex command to an array

Tags: arrays, bash

NOTE FROM OP:  Oops.  My mistake.  I happened to let grep hunt for something(s) non-existent.  Of course I got no output.  And yes, this is a dup of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753366/redirect-output-to-a-bash-array).

<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>

There are many answers on the web to (most of) this question.  The "most of" part is my problem.

How do I capture the output of a command line into a bash array when the command line contains pipe chars, "|"?

```
 array=($(ps -ef | grep myproc | grep -v grep))
```

doesn't work.  Neither does:

```
 array=(`ps -ef | grep myproc | grep -v grep`)
```

(those are backquotes in case your font mangles them).

And, can the given answer be use with **array+=** syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753366/redirect-output-to-a-bash-array

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? for me it works, I mean, I have no syntax error.

Comment: Well, it helps if you choose to pipe to grep for process names that actually exist.  Mea culpa.  Thanks fo all for the quick answers.

Comment: and where is a pipe character coming from in the output of `ps`? Better to edit in some intermediate results from actual runs so we can see what's going on. Good luck.

Comment: instead of `grep myproc | grep -v grep` if you hit: `grep m[y]proc`, the regex won't match itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array=($(ps -ef | grep myproc | grep -v grep))
```

works perfectly well. You can check it when you show the number of elements in your array

```
echo ${#array[*]}
```

or the complete array with

```
echo ${array[*]}
```

Comment: Mea CUlpa:  I happened to search for process names that weren't running.  Of course I had no output from ps.