# Bash output to multiple variales

Tags: bash

I'm creating a script in Bash to change all MAC addresses of my PC. I can list all network interfaces with this:

```
ip link | grep "<" | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1 | grep -v lo
```

And the output of the script is:

```
eth0
wlan0
```

Now I need to create a variable for each network interface (to use it in the future), but I don't know how, and Google didn't help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

```
readarray -t interfaces < <(ip link | grep "<" | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1 | grep -v lo)

echo "${interfaces[0]}" # prints eth0
echo "${interfaces[1]}" # prints wlan0
```

And to loop over them use `for`:

```
for curInterface in "${interfaces[@]}"; do
    echo "$curInterface"
done
```

#### But there are better ways to parse data:

First of all, instead of grepping `<` character you can use `-o` flag. This will output all of the data on single lines. Then you simply need the second word without `:` character. This is very simple in pure bash:

```
interfaces=()
while read -r _ curInterface _; do
    interfaces+=("${curInterface%:}")
done < <(ip -o link)
```

Comment: Not quite enough. You forgot `-t` to `readarray` making it include the newlines on the array as well. Also, your other way to parse data would place it on a subshell leaving `interfaces` to no value.

Comment: Seems like it was your first attempt to use `readarray`? ;) I also suggest using other variables beside `_` for the sake of good practice. Bash uses that variable as well.

Comment: @konsolebox of course not, I have simply forgot to write it because I was testing it in a terminal and out of laziness wrote ``echo ${curInterface[0]}`` without quotes. ``echo`` successfully trimmed the string and made me think that I'm done :) How does bash use ``_`` variable?

Comment: I see. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html -> I guess it's just an option to override the variable. I prefer using `__`. Actually I'm probably the only one who does that, unless someone copies my style :)

Comment: Thanks fou your help, but when I add 'readarray -t interfaces < <(ip link | grep "<" | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1 | grep -v lo)'
 the shell give me a error: 'Syntax error: redirection unexpected'
.... why¿? :(

Comment: @user2757192 that's because you're using ``sh`` instead of ``bash``. Change you [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) from ``#!/bin/sh`` to ``#!/bin/bash``.

Comment: @konsolebox well, it doesn't affect ``_`` in any way, so it is safe to use it.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko Yeah I guess that doesn't really matter in Bash. It's only in other shells where you need to have a workaround with it.

Comment: No, I have it in my script... :S

Comment: @user2757192 then how are you executing your script? Do it by ``./myscript`` Or you can even force bash by ``bash myscript``. But please prefer the first method

Comment: Yes, this was de problem... I open the script with sudo sh script.sh -.-" Thnks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from this output, and loop through it after.

```
my_array=( $(ip link | grep "<" | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1 | grep -v lo) )
```

You can also this exmaple giving different alternatives [redirect output to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753366/redirect-output-to-a-bash-array)

Answer (score 0):

Store the output in an array:

```
interfaces=( $(ip link | awk '/</ { print $2 }' | awk -F: '!/lo/ {print $1}') )
```

Answer (score 0):

And I could have it simpler like this with one awk command:

```
readarray -t youravar < <(exec ip link | awk -F': ' '/^[0-9]+:/&&!/ lo: /{print $2}')
```