# Tokenize split a string in bash using perl

Tags: bash, perl

I have a bash shell script.

I know how to tokenize a string in Perl using `split` function.
I know there is a method in Bash as well.
I prefer using the Perl function.

How could, if possible, Perl be used in bash to split a string and store in array?

Let's say string = "myaddr@mail.com;my2ndaddr@mail.com"

Comment: Do you need a regex to split the string? Or is it just a string, or even just a character?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking if a perl array can be used in bash: no, that data resides in a different process.

Given:

```sh
string="myaddr@mail.com;my2ndaddr@mail.com"
```

In bash, use

```sh
IFS=";" read -ra addresses <<< "$string"
```

If you really really want to use `split` in perl, you can do

```sh
mapfile -t addresses < <(
    perl -sle 'print for split /;/, $emails' -- -emails="$string"
)
```

Both solutions result in

```sh
$ declare -p addresses
declare -a addresses=([0]="myaddr@mail.com" [1]="my2ndaddr@mail.com")
```

---

Docs:
[`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read),
[`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile)

Comment: A bit of golf:  `perl -pe'y/;/\n/' <<<"$string"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```sh
v="myaddr@mail.com;my2ndaddr@mail.com"
IFS=$'\n' a=( $(perl -nE 'say for split /;/' <<< "$v") )
```

then `a` contains the email addresses.

As email addresses cannot contain withe-spaces, you can ignore the `IFS` part (*but this is for the more general case*).

Comment: That's just a complicated version of `IFS=\; a=( $v )`, right?

Comment: @ikegami right, but as the OP didn't mention what the delimiter could be this leaves room to add a more complex regex instead of just `;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would do this, but this comes to mind:

1. Create a separate Perl script that takes one argument.
2. Splits the string.
3. Prints each token to stdout.
4. Invoke the script from bash and give it the string
5. Capture the output in a bash array

[Redirect output to a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753366/redirect-output-to-a-bash-array)